# how to call a pg function with libpq and get the param value

Tags: c, postgresql, function, libpq

ALL
        I have a postgresql function,so this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION query_callouts(

    INOUT io_cursor_ref refcursor,
    INOUT opstatus integer,
    INOUT errtext character varying)
  RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

BEGIN

  OPEN $1 FOR
    SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables limit 10;
    --SELECT * from call_out_numbers;

  RETURN;
  Exception
    When Others Then
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS opstatus = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
                               errText = MESSAGE_TEXT;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION query_callouts(refcursor, integer, character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I want to known ,how to use libpq in my c codes to visit the function - query_callouts and get the param   io_cursor_ref  and opstatus and errtext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the function just like you are executing any query:

```
select * from query_callouts('mycur', 0, '');

 io_cursor_ref | opstatus | errtext
---------------+----------+---------
 mycur         |        0 |
(1 row)
```

`opstatus` and `errtext` would be set to the appropriate values if an exception occurs.
`io_cursor_ref` contains the name you have passed to the function.

> Internally, a refcursor value is simply the string name of a so-called
>   portal containing the active query for the cursor. This name can be
>   passed around, assigned to other refcursor variables, and so on,
>   without disturbing the portal.

Note, you can use a refcursor only within a transaction.

> All portals are implicitly closed at transaction end. Therefore a
>   refcursor value is usable to reference an open cursor only until the
>   end of the transaction.

You can use explicit transaction:

```
begin;
select * from query_callouts('mycur', 0, '');
fetch all in mycur;
-- save or show the query result
-- and finally
commit;
```

or use `mycur` inside a function.

The quotes are from [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-cursors.html).

Comment: this is can work in my psql,but how to work in my c/c++ code with libpq?

Comment: I do not know what you're asking. Your question should be more specific. 
[Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-example.html) you can find complete example programs, if you don't know how to use libpq.

Comment: oh, thank you, I get it code by your link,it is I need. I not use libpq to

Answer (score 0):

It's just like any other query.

```
SELECT * FROM query_callouts('cursorname', 4, 'msg')
```

I suspect some if not all of your parameters should be `OUT` parameters not `INOUT` parameters, though. You don't ever use the input value of `errtext` at least.